# Best way to make subapps with Traversal

Tags: python, pyramid, traversal

Ok so I have my apps, that takes requests from root `/` Almost everything is using traversal.

But i'd like to make on top of that site a rest api.

So I'm off with two choices. I either separate the that in two different apps and put that rest application to : `rest.site.com`, Or I can move it to site.com/rest/*traversal

If I'm doing "/rest/*traversal", I guess I'll have to add a route called `rest_traversal` where the traversal path will be `*traversal` with the route `/rest/*traversal`. I did that once for an admin page.

I was wondering if there was a cleanest way to do that. I tried to use virtual_root, but as I understand virtual_root is actually getting added to the path for traversal.

like having `virtual_root = /cms` and requesting `/fun` will create the following path `/cms/fun`

I on the other hand wish to have `/cms/fun` turned into `/fun`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using traversal already, why not just use it to return your "rest API root" object when Pyramid traverses to `/rest/`? From there, everything will work naturally.

```
class ApplicationRoot(object):

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        if name == "rest":
            return RestAPIRoot(parent=self, name=name)
        ...
```

If your "application tree" and "API tree" have the same children and you want to have different views registered for them depending on which branch of the tree the child is located in, you can use `containment` view predicate to register your API views, so they will only match when the child is inside the "API branch":

> **containment**
>
> This value should be a reference to a Python class or interface that a
>   parent object in the context resource’s lineage must provide in order
>   for this view to be found and called. The resources in your resource
>   tree must be “location-aware” to use this feature.
>
> If containment is not supplied, the interfaces and classes in the
>   lineage are not considered when deciding whether or not to invoke the
>   view callable.

Another approach would be not to build a separate "API tree" but to use your "main" application's "URI-space" as RESTful API. The only problem with this is that GET and possibly POST request methods are already "taken" on your resources and mapped to your "normal" views which return HTML or consume HTTP form POSTs. There are numerous ways to work around this:

- register the API views with a separate name, so, say `GET /users/123` would return HTML and `GET /users/123/json` would return a JSON object. Similarly, `POST /users/123` would expect HTTP form to be posted and `POST /users/123/json` would expect JSON. A nice thing about this approach is that you can easily add, say, an XML serializer at `GET /users/123/xml`.
- use custom view predicates so `GET /users/123` and `GET /users/123?format=json` are routed to different views. Actually, there's a built-in `request_param` predicate for that since Pyramid 1.2
- use `xhr` predicate to differentiate requests based on `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header or `accept` predicate to differentiate on `HTTP_ACCEPT` header

Comment: This is a good idea, didn't think about rerooting my tree. While it's half of an answer. Traversal will work naturally but will match the same views as before.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix:  I've expanded the answer a bit

Comment: nitpick: `match_param` is for matching patterns in routes. `request_param` is what you want for matching part of the `request.params` dictionary (query string + post body).

Comment: I tried and editing the tree is not a good idea with ZODB, it might work well when __parent__ isn't persistent value. I guess i'll use parameters like `HTTP_ACCEPT` which sounds to be the much cleanest way to do it. I'm not planning to use PUT and DELETE as it often creates problem with browsers that don't support it. I'll keep working with plain GET and POST with HTTP_ACCEPT to get my json.

Answer (score 3):

I know this has been answered already, but in case someone arrives here looking for another possible way to make "subapps" and using them in pyramid, I wanted to point out that some interesting things can be done with [pyramid.wsgi](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/api/wsgi.html)

```
"""
example of wsgiapp decorator usage
http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/api/wsgi.html
"""

from pyramid.wsgi import wsgiapp2, wsgiapp
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from webob import Request, Response
import pprint

# define some apps


def wsgi_echo(environ, start_response):
    """pretty print out the environ"""
    response = Response(body=pprint.pformat({k: v for k, v in environ.items()
                                             if k not in ["wsgi.errors",
                                                          "wsgi.input",
                                                          "SCRIPT_NAME"]}))
    return response(environ, start_response)


print Request.blank("/someurl").send(wsgi_echo).body


# convert wsgi app to a pyramid view callable
pyramid_echo = wsgiapp(wsgi_echo)
pyramid_echo_2 = wsgiapp2(wsgi_echo)

# wire up a pyramid application

config = Configurator()
config.add_view(pyramid_echo, name="foo")  # /foo
config.add_view(pyramid_echo, name="bar")  # /bar
config.add_view(pyramid_echo_2, name="foo_2")  # /foo
config.add_view(pyramid_echo_2, name="bar_2")  # /bar
pyramid_app = config.make_wsgi_app()

#call some urls
foo_body = Request.blank("/foo").send(pyramid_app).body
bar_body = Request.blank("/bar").send(pyramid_app).body
foo_body_2 = Request.blank("/foo_2").send(pyramid_app).body
bar_body_2 = Request.blank("/bar_2").send(pyramid_app).body

# both should be different because we arrived at 2 different urls
assert foo_body != bar_body, "bodies should not be equal"

# should be equal because wsgiapp2 fixes stuff before calling
# application in fact there's an additional SCRIPT_NAME in the
# environment that we are filtering out
assert foo_body_2 == bar_body_2, "bodies should be equal"

# so how to pass the path along? like /foo/fuuuu should come back
# /fuuuu does it
foo_body = Request.blank("/foo_2/fuuuu").send(pyramid_app).body
assert "'/fuuuu'," in foo_body, "path didn't get passed along"


# tldr: a wsgi app that is decorated with wsgiapp2 will recieve data
# as if it was mounted at "/", any url generation it has to do should
# take into account the SCRIPT_NAME variable that may arrive in the
# environ when it is called
```